# SSIS package written in 2008 run on 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have an SSIS package that I wrote in 2008 and I need to run on server that has 2005.

I know I can not convert the 2008 down to 2005.

My question is can I copy the 2008 version of DTEXEC.exe from the 2008 server to the 2005 server and just point my jobs to use the 2008 version I copied to the 2005 server?

I am not sure if there is other files/etc that are needed or different versions of DLL's, etc.  Or is the DTEXEC.EXE a standalone program and what I am proposing will work?

Comment: Is there something preventing you from running the package on a 2008 server but change the target database connection strings to the 2005 server? (Using the SQL Destination would be an example of said thing)

Comment: If that's not an option, you might have luck with [SSIS Downgrade](http://ssisctc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SSIS%20Downgrade). It attempts to convert a 2008 package to 2005 format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just copying the .exe wont help. The dtexec.exe is going to look for the required DLL files and when it doesnt find those, it will fail. You will need to either install 2008 or redesign the package in 2005.

Comment: Ok, not what I was hoping for, but what I expected.

Is there something I can install that is just 2008 DTEXEC.exe only and it will work on the 2005 server and 2008 packages (in SSIS 2005)?

Or do I need to install 2008 SSIS (integrated services)?

A couple will be easy to rewrite in 2005 but 1 is quite large, took me a while to write and test, now I will have to rewrite and retest it.

Comment: From what I have read at http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic784347-148-1.aspx#bm784713 you just cannot do that. The basic difference is the .net environment that is used by both. 2005 probably uses .net 2.0 and 2008 uses 3.5. The code that's behind the GUI is quite different in both (as I would expect). Your best shot is to have it redesigned in 2005. Sorry to say, but sometimes it just doesnt work.

Comment: Well again not what I wanted to hear but figured that was the case

Thank You